# Camera not being properly released

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-mediarecorder

It appears somehow the [Camera](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) I'm using in this activity is not being properly released. Why do I say this? Because if I quit the app and open the device's native camera app it crashes. Then if I uninstall my app, it works fine.

The activity uses the camera to record a video, using the following classes: [Camera](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html), [MediaRecorder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) and [TextureView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html).

### Here's the activity's relevant code:

Initialization of the TextureView in `onCreate()`:

```
TextureView textureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.textureview);
textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
```

*OnSurfaceTextureAvailable* method:

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
    mCamera = Camera.open();
    mCamera.setPreviewTexture(surface);
    mCamera.startPreview();
    isPreviewRunning = true;
}
```

*OnSurfaceTextureUpdated* method:

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
    if (!isRecording) {
        if (isPreviewRunning){
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.lock();
        }

        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

        Size highest_size = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes().get(0);
        int[] fps_range = parameters.getSupportedPreviewFpsRange().get(0);

        parameters.setPreviewSize(highest_size.width, highest_size.height);
        parameters.setPreviewFpsRange(fps_range[0], fps_range[1]);

        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

        mCamera.setPreviewTexture(surface);
        mCamera.startPreview();
        isPreviewRunning = true;    

        prepareRecorder(surface);   
    }
}
```

*PrepareRecorder* method:

```
private void prepareRecorder(SurfaceTexture surface) {
    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    mCamera.unlock();
    mRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
    mRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    // Other settings, using CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH

    mRecorder.prepare();
}
```

*OnSurfaceTextureDestroyed* method:

```
@Override
public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
    if (isPreviewRunning) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        isPreviewRunning = false;
    }

    if (isRecording) {
        mRecorder.stop();
        isRecording = false;
    }

    mRecorder.release();
    mCamera.release();

    mRecorder = null;
    mCamera = null;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Did you found a workaround?